# Replace character in substring after character using SED or AWK

Tags: awk, sed

I have a dynamic string and need to replace a character within the string but only in the last portion of the string.

Example String:

```
Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application-local
```

I need to replace the "-" in the string with a ":" but only in the last portion of the string.

Desired String:

```
Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application:local
```

The data in the string changes with the exception of the "win:". Would it be possible to say starting at "win:" look to the end of the string replace any "-" with ":"

I am having a hard time getting my logic straight.

Comment: do you have some failed attempts? post the same

Comment: `sed -e 's/\(win:[^-]*\)-/\1:/'`

Comment: `echo "$s" | rev | sed 's/-/:/' | rev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
$ s='Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application-local'
```

With sed:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -e 's/\(win:[^-]*\)-\([^-]*$\)/\1:\2/'
Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application:local
```

Or Perl:

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -lpe 's/(win:[^-]*)-([^-]*)$/\1:\2/'
Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application:local
```

If the `win:...` part is always the last, you don't need the second capturing group.

Comment: Thanks I greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

If using sed or awk is not mandatory then [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to the rescue:

```sh
STR="Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application-local"
echo ${STR%-*}:${STR##*-}
```

In the snippet above

`${STR%-*}` means "STR without the shortest match of the `-*` regexp from the tail"

and `${STR##*-}` means "STR without the longest of the `*-` regexp from the head"

Comment: Thanks I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {sub(/-/,":",$NF)} 1' file
Microsoft|Application-Local|Installed on system|win:application:local
```

Some (maybe all, idk - test them) of the other solutions posted so far would work for the 1 sample input line you provided but fail given different input such as input that doesn't have a `-` in that final field or input that doesn't have some specific strings like `win` in the final field or does have it in an earlier field, etc. so you might want to come up with some more comprehensive input/output covering all of your use cases to test against.

Comment: Thanks Ed greatly appreciate the help.